# Overriding a complicated Symfony2 class - best practice

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.3 LTS which I believe is slightly different to the latest version (for the parts of my question).

I need to override the 'security.authentication.listener.form' service, which is this class: https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/2.3/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php

I just want to add a little bit of code, nothing major.

These are the parts of the declaration that matter (in Symfony config files):

```
    <parameter key="security.authentication.listener.form.class">Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener</parameter>

    <service id="security.authentication.listener.form"
             class="%security.authentication.listener.form.class%"
             parent="security.authentication.listener.abstract"
             abstract="true">
    </service>

    <service id="security.authentication.listener.abstract" abstract="true" public="false">
        <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="security" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.authentication.manager" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.authentication.session_strategy" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.http_utils" />
        <argument />
        <argument type="service" id="security.authentication.success_handler" />
        <argument type="service" id="security.authentication.failure_handler" />
        <argument type="collection"></argument>
        <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="null" />
        <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher" on-invalid="null" />
    </service>
```

There are also two additional important points:

```
(1) I only have experience using Yaml and although it shouldn't be difficult converting this, it does add an additional obstacle to deal with. I will also use Yaml for my finished solution. I've never seen the on-invalid attribute though for a start.
(2) I need to pass in some additional parameters of my own.
```

I've tried just overriding the class name and a basic class extension to see if it works without error, but I don't think any of the passed-in values are being used:

Yaml:

```
parameters:
  security.authentication.listener.form.class: MyBundle\Security\MyCustomUsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
```

PHP class:

```
class MyCustomUsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener extends UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener
{
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $securityContext, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager, SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface $sessionStrategy, HttpUtils $httpUtils, $providerKey, AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface $successHandler, AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface $failureHandler, array $options = array(), LoggerInterface $logger = null, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher = null, CsrfProviderInterface $csrfProvider = null)
{
    parent::__construct($securityContext, $authenticationManager, $sessionStrategy, $httpUtils, $providerKey, $successHandler, $failureHandler, $options, $logger, $dispatcher, $csrfProvider);
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
{
    parent::attemptAuthentication($request);
}
```

}

Also, I don't understand why parameter 5 in the 'security.authentication.listener.abstract' service is empty yet the class will throw an error if it is empty (but doesn't).

Also, I don't see the security.authentication.listener.form service as an option in the security config (http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/security.html). If not I could just override as I've mentioned above, but it might be better to declare it in security.yml if possible.

So what's the best practice way to do this - in Yaml? I could hack it someway, cut and paste etc. but ideally I won't need to redeclare all the arguments as they're already declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to answer why you can't see the security.authentication.listener.form service as an option in the security config (http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/configuration/security.html):

- In app/config/security.yml you will find the configuration options for the security bundle and component. These are options that can be editable from configuration files from app folder. The configs that are located in bundles, inside the folder /Resources/config can be edited only using a [compilerPass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html).

Now to your main problem, the solution depends on what you're trying to do:

- If you use directly that class, you may want to send it to a decorator and use that decorator to your needs
- If not, you can do this:
  To your services.yml add:

  ```
  acme.security.authentication.listener.form:
     class: %security.authentication.listener.form.class%
     parent: security.authentication.listener.abstract
     abstract: true
  ```

  Then [create a CompilerPass inside your Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/compiler_passes.html) and add this to it:

  ```
  public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
  {
       $definition = new DefinitionDecorator( 'acme.security.authentication.listener.form' );
       $definition->setClass( 'Acme\Bundle\MyCustomUsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener' );
       $definition->setAbstract( true );

       // Here you can add your additional data
       $definition->setMethodCalls($callsArray);

       $container->setDefinition( 'security.authentication.listener.form', $definition );
  }
  ```

You can overwrite the `security.authentication.listener.form` without a compilerpass, inside your Resources/config/services.yml, only if your bundle is initiated after the SecurityBundle. But it is a practice that I do not recommend. When using a CompilerPass you will always be sure that it runs after all bundles are initialized.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work. The setParent method doesn't exist in the Definition class. Also, is this right, I create a new service and set my new service as the parent? It doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: `$container->getDefinition('security.authentication.listener.form');` shoud return a `DefinitionDecorator` instance, not a `Definition` instance. And a `DefinitionDecorator` has a method setParent. I have just tested it and it works. Be sure you followed the steps exactly. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again for the help, but I must be missing something. I see that the getDefinition method returns an instance of Definition in http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.html#method_getDefinition. Also, I don't see the setParent method in http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/DefinitionDecorator.html anyway.

Comment: I have edited my answer, the process method from CompilerPass. Can you try with this new "solution"?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have managed to complete this now. Using all the advice you offered I think I have the finished solution. I couldn't have achieved this solution without your help. I have added the solution to your answer.